# How to get the last index of a string that starts with X from a list in C#?

Tags: c#

So I made a list containing lines from an html document and I'm trying to get the index of last CSS reference made (to append a new reference after it). The following code does not work for me.

```
string prefix = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\""; //goal is to find last line that starts with this.

LineList = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();

int index = LineList.LastIndexOf(prefix);
```

I'm guessing `.LastIndexOf()` only works on exactly defined strings. How would I find the index of the last line that starts with (or contains) `prefix`?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to find the index in a string, or the index in a list? It's unclear at the moment. Do you actually need the index, or just the line itself? The answers to these questions will affect what you should do. (To find the last line index, I'd probably just use a `for` loop. For anything else, I'd use LINQ.)

Comment: @NicoRiff: That won't even compile. The string literal is not the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LINQ` and string method `StartsWith` like this:

```
string prefix = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\""; //goal is to find last line that starts with this.

List<string> LineList = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();
int index = LineList.Select((n, i) => new { Value = n, Index = i })
    .LastOrDefault(x => x.Value.StartsWith(prefix))
    .Index;
```

The idea above is to create index for this list and then choose the last one which `StartsWith` the prefix.

If looping can be used, you could also create simple looping starting from the last element and return the first index of the element which starts with the `prefix`

Answer (score 1):

Well, simply iterate backwards through the lines enumeration until you reach the first one that meets your criteria:

```
for (var i = lineList.Count -1 ; i != 0; i--)
{
    if (lineList[i].StartsWith("<link rel=\"stylesheet\"")
    {
        return i;
    }
}

return -1;
```

You could do this with with linq but I think you need to grasp some basics first.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you want to find **last line that starts with** and you're searching for line that equals your `prefix`.

To fix this I recommend this using this code :

```
string prefix = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\""; //goal is to find last line that starts with this.
LineList = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();
int index = LineList.Select( (line, index) => new { text = line, idx = index }).LastOrDefault( a => a.line.StartsWith(prefix).idx;
```

Another way you can achieve this is to use for loop and just assign index of current iteration:

```
string prefix = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\""; //goal is to find last line that starts with this.
LineList = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();
int index = -1;
for( int i = 0; i < LineList.Length; i++)
    if(LineList[i].StartsWith(prefix)) index = i;
}
```

Or you can use simplies `Linq` possible :

```
string prefix = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\""; //goal is to find last line that starts with this.
LineList = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();
int index = LineList.IndexOf(LineList.LastOrDefault(line => line.StartsWith(prefix)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Query the list to get the item:

```
var item = LineList.Where(x => x.StartsWith(prefix)).LastOrDefault();
```

Then use the item to get the index:

```
int index = -1;
if (item != null)
    index = LineList.IndexOf(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```cs
string prefix = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\""; //goal is to find last line that starts with this.

LineList = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();

int index = LineList.IndexOf(LineList.LastOrDefault(l => l.Contains(prefix)));
```